# Show/hide lines/data in Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts

I'm trying to make a google line chart with 2 lines in it.

You should be able to turn them on and off(show/hide) by two checkboxes..

Anyone got any idea show to make this, og just give some pointers?

My guess would be some onClick jQuery stuff?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);
        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try this

Mark up:

```
 <body>
   <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

   <button type="button" id="hideSales"  >Hide Sales</button>
   <button type="button" id="hideExpenses"  >Hide Expence</button>

 </body>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);
    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);


   var hideSal = document.getElementById("hideSales");
   hideSal.onclick = function()
   {
      view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.hideColumns([1]); 
      chart.draw(view, options);
   }
   var hideExp = document.getElementById("hideExpenses");
   hideExp.onclick = function()
   {
      view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.hideColumns([2]); 
      chart.draw(view, options);
   }


  }


</script>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. OP clearly asked to switch series on and off again using checkboxes and the highest-rated answer does not do this.

Comment: Not to mention, this solution is much easier to understand.

Comment: @Arfan 
try chart.draw(data, options); again to  redraw.

Answer (score 23):

To get your required output check this code.

```js
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    var sel = chart.getSelection();
    // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
    if (sel.length > 0) {
        // if row is null, we clicked on the legend
        if (sel[0].row == null) {
            var col = sel[0].column;
            if (columns[col] == col) {
                // hide the data series
                columns[col] = {
                    label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
                    type: data.getColumnType(col),
                    calc: function () {
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                
                // grey out the legend entry
                series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
            }
            else {
                // show the data series
                columns[col] = col;
                series[col - 1].color = null;
            }
            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns(columns);
            chart.draw(view, options);
        }
    }
});
```

Instead of having a checkbox, use the legend to hide/show the lines.

Comment: @PhilippTsipman your JSFiddle is not working please check the updated : http://jsfiddle.net/xDUPF/53/

Comment: -1. OP asked to use checkboxes for this, and this answer does not satisfy that requirement. The implementation of toggling series using checkboxes vs. a legend is largely different, and incompatible. [This answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17446392/366529) is the correct approach for what is being asked. @abinaya, this is the second time I've seen you copy/paste this answer what was a question specifically about checkboxes; I don't think either actually answer the questions correctly.

Answer (score 9):

Recently the behavior of the `select` event changed so Abinaya Selvaraju's answer needs a slight fix

```
if (typeof sel[0].row === 'undefined') {
    ...
}
```

becomes

```
if (sel[0].row == null) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited Abinaya Selvaraju's answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I updated the solution provided by Shinov T to allow real toggling (show/hide) of columns. You can see the result in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Loxos/rmbtwdhd/).

I added this code to save the current state of each column to allow toggleing:

```
var toggleSales = document.getElementById("toggleSales");
var salesHidden = false;
toggleSales.onclick = function() {
  salesHidden = !salesHidden;
  view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  if (salesHidden) {
    view.hideColumns([1]);
  }
  chart.draw(view, options);
}

var toggleExp = document.getElementById("toggleExpenses");
var expHidden = false;
toggleExp.onclick = function() {
  expHidden = !expHidden;
  view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  if (expHidden) {
    view.hideColumns([2]);
  }
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```