# LineChart with certain columns

Tags: google-visualization

i am displaying a line chart and have data toggle on/off set up based on the answer (given by Abinaya Selvaraju) here:

[Show/hide lines/data in Google Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444586/show-hide-lines-data-in-google-chart)

it works great.

now i want to certain columns to be automatically grayed out when the chart first displays.

i think i need to do something like what's shown in the answer and came up with this:

```
for (var regionCol=0; regionCol<chartData.getNumberOfColumns();regionCol++){
      if ((regionCol >= 2) && (regionCol <=7)){   
            columns[regionCol] = {
                 label: chartData.getColumnLabel(regionCol),
                 type: chartData.getColumnType(regionCol),
                 calc: function () {
                         return null;
                 }
             };

             // grey out the legend entry
             //series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
             series[Math.floor(regionCol/3)].color = '#CCCCCC';
       }
       else{
             // show the data series
             columns[regionCol] = regionCol;
             //series[col - 1].color = null;
             series[Math.floor(regionCol/3)].color = null;
       }
 }
 var viewToHideRegions = new google.visualization.DataView(chartData);
 viewToHideRegions.setColumns(columns);
 chart.draw(viewToHideRegions, options);
 /* code to set regions to be hidden */
```

This is how my chart data is defined:

```
 chartData.addColumn('string', 'Date'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
 chartData.addColumn('number', colIdxName); // Implicit domain label col.
 chartData.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
 chartData.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotationText'});
 chartData.addColumn('number', dpndata[colGenIdx]['name']); // Implicit domain label col.
 chartData.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
 chartData.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotationText'});
```

When I run all of this, i get the message "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type"

I can't spot what I've got wrong.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things you need to fix here.  First, you only have 7 columns, and the column indices start at 0, so checking column indices 2-7 will start too late and overflow the end of the column list.  Second, you always want your domain column (index 0) to be included, but you don't want to list it in the `series` option.  Third, the "annotation" and "annotationText" columns need to have their roles specified in the view.

Your code should look something like this (to grey out all series by default):

```
var columns = [0];
for (var regionCol = 1; regionCol < chartData.getNumberOfColumns(); regionCol++) {
    columns[regionCol] = {
        label: chartData.getColumnLabel(regionCol),
        type: chartData.getColumnType(regionCol),
        role: chartData.getColumnProperty(regionCol, 'role'),
        calc: function () {
            return null;
        }
    };

    // grey out the legend entry
    if (regionCol % 3 == 1) {
        series[Math.floor(regionCol / 3) - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
    }
}
var viewToHideRegions = new google.visualization.DataView(chartData);
viewToHideRegions.setColumns(columns);
chart.draw(viewToHideRegions, options);
/* code to set regions to be hidden */
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply.

i'm still having some problems.  what is the variable "i" in the if statmement?  should it be "regionCol" ?

what does "series" represent?

Comment: Sorry, `i` should be `regionCol`.  If your code is based on the example jsfiddle that I wrote on turning data series on and off by clicking legend entries (it appears to be: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6gz2Q/), then `series` is tied into the `options` object (see the fiddle for details).

Comment: yes, my code is based on your example!  based on your advice, my problems is 99% solved.  when the chart first displays I am able to hide columns 2-7.  they appear gray in the legend.  however, their lines also appear as grey in the chart.  i'd like to hide their lines completely, until the user clicks on their entry in the legend.  at that point i'd like the line to display.

can you suggest how to make that happen?

Comment: They should not be drawing in the chart, since the columns used in the `viewToHideRegions` view are all returning `null`.  Can you update your post (or create a jsfiddle) with your full code?

Comment: I will gladly update the post or create a jsfiddle in a few hours after work - i'm only about halfway thru the workday here.

Comment: i reviewed my code and had left off the last 3 lines in your example.

once i added them, it worked exactly as desired.

sorry about that.