# Show/Hide Lines/Data in Google Chart Implementation

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I've been looking for a way to click on/off google line charts from the legend. In my searches I came across this code on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444586/show-hide-lines-data-in-google-chart):

```
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
        var sel = chart.getSelection();
        // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
        if (sel.length > 0) {
            // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
            if (sel[0].row === null) {
                var col = sel[0].column;
                if (columns[col] == col) {
                    // hide the data series
                    columns[col] = {
                        label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
                        type: data.getColumnType(col),
                        calc: function () {
                            return null;
                        }
                    };

                    // grey out the legend entry
                    series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
                }
                else {
                    // show the data series
                    columns[col] = col;
                    series[col - 1].color = null;
                }
                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                view.setColumns(columns);
                chart.draw(view, options);
            }
        }
    });
```

(associated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xDUPF/53/ )

However, I'm having trouble applying it to my chart, no matter where I put it in the scheme of things I either have no effect or no chart = \

Could anyone help me understand where in my code this needs to go? (I'm sorry, not a coder, just kinda stringing bits together to get something to work)

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);

function drawChart1() {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Month');
    //loop from above for store and store base
    <?php echo($cstores); ?>
    dataTable.addRows([

    <?php 

        $sql = "SELECT
                QUOTE(DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted,'%b-%y')) AS 'Month'
                ". $string ."
            FROM data 
            WHERE store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ")
            GROUP BY YEAR(date_submitted), MONTH(date_submitted)
            ORDER BY YEAR(date_submitted) ASC, MONTH(date_submitted) ASC";

        $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        foreach( $query as $key => $array ) {
            echo("[");
            foreach( $array as $attribute => $value ) {
                echo str_replace("|","\\n",$value) . ","; //couldn't put \\n in the SQL above as it rendered in the output and broke it, so replacing the | here with \\n so it renders properly in the chart
            }
            echo("],");
        }
    ?> 

    ]);

   var options = {
      title: '',
      vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 10,
        <?php if($submittedValue == 3){ // adjust chart scale and axis if MPO
            echo("format: '#\'%\'',");
            echo("title: 'Percent',");
        }
        else{
            echo("title: 'Score 0-10'");
        }
        ?>
        },
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        },
      pointSize: 10,
      pointShape: 'diamond'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }
```

The `$cstores` just outputs a dynamic column header for the chart and then I fetch in some SQL depending on a form to match which makes my chart quite dynamic (all thanks to people here on StackOverflow) just struggling to get this last bit done!

Thank you

Comment: the code is an event listener on the chart, and should be added after the chart is created --> `var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart` -- and before the chart is drawn --> `chart.draw` -- note: you can check for errors in the browser's console, press F12...

Comment: Thanks, is there maybe something I need to edit in the code to match my chart then, as, when I place it between those two lines clicking on a legend item does the usual highlight, clicking it again (or any other legend item) does nothing (ie, doesn't unhighlight nor highlight anything else).